# bulk upload through fileupload with rails is very slow

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I am trying to use jquery fileupload to upload a bunch of files to server. I have a form which i use to upload multiple files (around 1500 at a time). The total size is not much -66 mb or so. Yet, the file upload process takes to much time to even start.

There is no JS response for a long time and the browser freezes.  I just have an upload progressbar and and error for the list of files that are not successfully uploaded.

What can i remove/ what should I do to make this process faster?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var maxFiles = 100000;
var filestoupload =0;   
  $(function () {
      // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
      $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        autoUpload: true,
        progressall: function (e, data) {
          var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
          $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
              'width',
              progress + '%'
          );
          document.getElementById('progress_value').innerHTML = progress+ '%';
        },
        submit: function (event, files) {
            var fileCount = files.originalFiles.length;
            document.getElementById('total_files').innerHTML = fileCount.toString()+' file(s) for upload';
            if (fileCount > maxFiles) {
                alert(fileCount + " files at a time? The max number of files uploadable at a time is "+maxFiles);
                throw 'This is not an error. This is just to abort javascript';
                return false; 
            }
        }

      });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Use delayed_job or resque to move these jobs into background

Comment: I am already using backburner for multiple workers, is it possible to use backburner instead of delayed_job or resque ?

Comment: if not , is ti possible to use both delayed_job and backburner at the same time?

Comment: Haven't worked with backburner but seeing the docs , it's advisable to use beanstalkd with backburner . Give it a spin and see how it goes .